# Error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’ when compiling in command line with gcc 4.8.2, works in NetBeans?

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans, googletest, g++4.8

I am doing tests for my code with GoogleTest (1.7.0). I must have the tests compiling in both NetBeans (8.0.2) and straight from command line.

NetBeans has GoogleTest integrated as suggested here: https://youtu.be/TS2CTf11k1U.
I have also build GoogleTest from the command line (in different place) with the instructions provided with the package.

The problematic line of code is (a and b are doubles):

```
std::string input = std::to_string(a) + " " + std::to_string(b);
```

which gives `error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’`, when compiling with

```
g++ -isystem -std=c++0x ~/gtest-1.7.0/include -pthread ~/Task1/test_source.cpp libgtest.a -o test_module1_1
```

as instructed in GoogleTest documentation.

The strange thing here is that when using the "Test" from NetBeans (as seen on video), the tests compile and run correctly.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have already tried to update g++ (not to a higher version though), and I have also tried specifying the version with `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=c++0x`.

In NetBeans there is this warning visible:

```
Library File /usr/include/c++/4.8/string
but there is an unresolved #include <stddef.h>
in included /usr/include/_G_config.h
```

I found out that this might be because multilib and I have also tried to fix that by checking that it is installed. And this doesn't really cause any warnings during compile so it might be just that the IDE is confused.

But conserning the real problem about compile errors:
Is there something wrong with the GoogleTest framework, the compiler or my code?

PS. Preferably don't suggest that I just don't use to_string as this system must be usable by students studying C++11 and really it shouldn't be that they can't use all the functionality that should be supported.

Comment: @Praetorian As I said I am using Ubuntu 14.04, so no MinGW.

Comment: If you're using a new g++ you should be passing std=c++11 instead of c++0x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the order in which you're passing command line arguments to gcc

```
g++ -isystem -std=c++0x ~/gtest-1.7.0/include ...
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `-isystem` flag should be followed by a path that contains headers which you want gcc to treat as [system headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html). So the `-std=c++0x` flag is being incorrectly consumed by the `-isystem` flag. You probably want the command line to be

```
g++ -std=c++0x -isystem ~/gtest-1.7.0/include ...
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that!